# DataBinding with a layer class

Tags: c#

When I have a middleman layer class that holds my list of objects, ListBox I use cannot populate the DisplayMembers properly. Without Layer class everything is fine but I need it for my project. Here's a very simplified example;

Passenger

```
class Passenger
{
        private string name;

        public Passenger(string custName)
        {
            name = custName;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
        }
}
```

Plane

```
class Plane
{
        public List<LayerClass> passengerList;

        public Plane()
        {
            // Using this instead of using Passenger, 
            // if Passenger is used there are no problems
            passengerList = new List<LayerClass>(); 
        }
}
```

Layer Class

```
class LayerClass
 {
        private Passenger p;
        private int ID;

        public Passenger P
        {
            get { return p; }
            set { p = value; }
        }
 }
```

Let's say I populate the plane with three passenger names, then code below;

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = plane.passengerList;

aListBox.DataSource = bs;
aListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

aListBox will display multiple lines of text "***DataBinding.TestApp,LayerClass***" instead of the names of the passengers.
If I insert this code, `bs.DataMember = "P";` or `aListBox.DisplayMember = "P.Name";`, It will only display the first passenger's name in the ListBox and ignore all other names.

How can I display all passenger names in the ListBox? Without overriding ToString() method of the Passenger class. Could be something simple that I am missing but I am new to DataBinding. This is a Windows Forms application with strict restrictions on what I am allowed to use. No XAML or WPF are allowed.

Comment: @Alex...try adding Name as a property to the LayerClass that returns p.Name.  Also, do you get the same number of rows in the ListBox as there are in the passengerList

Comment: @MikeTWebb The number of rows are same yes, it matches to number of passengers in this example. On my actual project which is way larger than this example, I am deserializing xml into objects and there are multiple properties exist. I also have to follow design pattern rules, so the middle man has a specific purpose where I most likely can't modify it other than what it's doing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like two things.  As mentioned, try using a Property instead of a Field for the list:

```
public List<LayerClass> PassengerList { get; private set; }
```

and then it looks like the BindingSource doesn't work right, so try eliminating it:

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "P.Name";
listBox1.DataSource = plane.PassengerList;
```

Or you can just override the ToString function in your LayerClass:

```
class LayerClass
{
  private Passenger p;
  private int ID;

  public Passenger P
  {
    get { return p; }
    set { p = value; }
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    if (p == null) {
      return "No Passenger";
    } else {
      return p.Name;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, binding list directly to listBox brings out the same results. Property doesn't make a difference as well.

Comment: @Alex This worked on my machine.  Make sure to use the "P.Name" as the DisplayMember property.

Comment: Were you able to display all of the names in the list or just one? If you're referring to Overriding ToString(), that is not something I want to do as I mentioned in my question, I will have many properties to choose from on my actual project and Windows UI code is not the only project that uses this middle man class, I should not change the behavior of it just to make it work with UI project.

Comment: Yes, the top part of my answer was working and it showed all 10 passengers in my list.  The ToString override was just another way to get it to work since your post mentioned overriding the Passenger class, not the LayerClass.

Comment: Interesting that it works for you but in a limited way for me. I'll investigate this further to see why I only get one result, I'll also check ListBox settings and other things I can find. Kind of puzzled at the moment.

Comment: @Alex Make sure none of your Passenger objects are null.

Comment: Objects are not null and this is still not working for me. I'll accept this as the answer, I am going with the option overriding ToString() since I can get this to work with only that option when there's a layer class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use property

```
     public List<LayerClass> passengerList { get; set; }
```

instead of just public field

Comment: Thanks. Converting that to property causes the same results as the public member.

Answer (score 0):

This is your Passenger class structure.

```
class Passenger
{
    private Int32 id;
    private string name;

    public Passenger(Int32 _id, string custName)
    {
        id = _id;
        name = custName;            
    }

    public Int32 ID
    {
        get { return id; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
    }
}
```

This is your Plane class structure.

```
class Plane
{
    List<Passenger> lPassengers = null;
    public Plane()
    {

    }

    public List<Passenger> Passengers
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.lPassengers == null)
                this.lPassengers = new List<Passenger>();

            return this.lPassengers;
        }
        set { this.lPassengers = value; }
    }
}
```

When you populate the generic list simply do the following. Also I assume you have a dataset. If not you can change this loop.

```
Plane objPlane = new Plane();
foreach(DataRow DR in objDS.Tables[0].Rows)
    obj.Plane.Passengers.Add(new Passenger(Int32.Parse(DR["id"].ToString()), DR["name"].ToString()));
```

ListBox DataBinding

```
this.aListBox.DataSource = objPlane.Passengers; 
this.aListBox.DataValueField = "ID";
this.aListBox.DataTextField = "Name";
this.aListBox.DataBind();
```